# How to Return no.of hyperlinks and ids of whole web site

Tags: javascript, html

How can i get link ids and the length of links of a whole web site using html or javascript

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Number of links you can get with ​`document.getElementsByTagName('a').length` but IDs would require a loop.

Comment: @j08691 that's for a single webpage, not a whole website.

Comment: @Griffin - yup, I misread the question.

Comment: I want no.of links of a web site not a page.:-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

You need to crawl the website using some server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to pull in each of the pages with javascript and get the count of each one. You can pull in all the content with AJAX and do this, but it wouldn't be reccomended to do this for anything beyond pulling it for your personal information because it would take a long time to parse everything.

For an individual page it would be something like:

HTML

```
<div id="resultDiv"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#resultDiv').load('ajax/test.html', function() { //Use the URL of the page
    var anchors = $('#resultDiv').getElementsByTagName("a");
    var anchorCount = anchors.length;
});
```

You would then do this for each of your pages and keep a running count. You can also loop through the anchors to get the IDs and text length.

Comment: Ok.but i dont know Ajax . There is no such a procedure in javascript

Comment: AJAX is javascript. JQuery has some nice built in ways to do this and a nice example page. You could output the content to a DIV and then run the JavaScript that Whymarrh suggested to search within that div instead of the document.

Comment: Can u give the code for pull in each of page?:-)

Comment: Added an example for a single page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName("a");` which returns an array of all the anchor tags on a single page. Given that, you can loop through them and pick out the attributes you need, id, etc.